# Special character not displaying as expected

Tags: html, utf-8

I have the following simple HTML page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        méywe
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When displaying it in Chrome or Firefox (I did not test other browsers), I see the following:

m�ywe

What did I miss? The html file is saved in UTF-8 encoding. The server is Apache. My machine is Windows 7 pro. The text editor is UltraEdit.

Thanks!

**Update**

Initially, I used UltraEdit for editing this html file and I got the problem. Based on **cmbuckley**'s input and install of Notepad++ (from **Heatmanofurioso**'s suggestion), I thought about the possibility of my file being corrupt somehow (even though it looks fine in both UltraEdit and Notepad). So I saved my file with Notepad in utf-8 encoding. Still saw the problem (maybe due to cache???). Then I used UltraEdit to save it again. See the page in the browser and the problem is gone.

**Lesson Learned**

Have two text editors if that that is your tool, and try the different one if you see unexplainable problem. No tool is perfect, even though you use one everyday. In my case, Notepad++ fixed the utf8 issue with my file that UltraEdit somehow failed.

**Thanks to folks for helping!!!**

Comment: may be thats because, the font is not supported by the browser.

Comment: What is the encoding that the browsers render the page as? I know it should be UTF-8, but it also shouldn't be causing troubles either....

Comment: If the font in use doesn't have the character in it the browser uses that character as a placeholder. What font are you using?

Comment: Are you sure it's in UTF-8? What does `hexdump -C file.html` show? The bytes for `méywe` should be `6d c3 a9 79 77 65`, where `c3 a9` is `é`.

Comment: isherwood, I did not add any font specs. Browsers use their defaults. In Chrome, I found out it is Times New Roman under Computed style. Cannot find this info in Firefox.

Comment: cmbuckley, I dont have hexdump on my machine. I use Windows pro 7.

Comment: Just to coment on the part that you showed great interest in trying to solve your problem. And made an update in the end with the answers you achieved and how you got them. Not many people do that, and if i could upvote your question more, i would. i don't see that kind of interest much these days. Awessome!

Comment: I think you mean "Lesson learned: Use a real editor which gives you  complete control over this, and learn to use it properly." #oneEmacsToBindThem

Comment: I was having a similar problem. We use `html-pdf` nodeJS package to print invoices from the HTML Templates. After deploying the module on oure Ubuntu server, the generated invoice PDF did not display the Indian Language text properly. Solution was to install the fonts on the server itself and then restart the processes. `fonts-indic` was the package that we installed. Hope somebody finds this useful.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

1 - Replace your

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

with

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

2 - Check if your HTML Editor's encoding is in UTF8. Usually this option is found on the tabs on the top of the program, like in Notepad++.

3 - Check if your browser is compatible with your font, if you're somehow importing a font. Or try and add a css to set your fonts to a default/generally accepted one like

```
body
{
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Why downvote my answer?
At least explain why, please

Comment: Just tried the style and meta change. None is working. Somebody else downvoted. Thanks for chiming in!

Comment: Just installed Notepad++. Double-checked the encoding to make it utf8. Still got the same issue.

Comment: This is a really long shot. But try fully cleaning yoour browsers cache.

Comment: Good insight on changing the editor's encoding. I inherited a legacy site that used ISO-8859-1 and switching to UTF-8 fixed the problem. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Option 2 worked for me. In my case i'm using MobaXterm and the built-in editor was using ANSI for some reason.

Answer (score 10):

The reason for having saved the file with [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding (most likely) instead of [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding resulting in getting the non-[ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) character displayed wrong in the browsers was missing knowledge about UTF-8 detection by UltraEdit and perhaps also appropriate UTF-8 configuration.

How currently latest version 22.10 of UltraEdit detects UTF-8 encoding is explained in detail in user-to-user forum topic [UTF-8 not recognized, largish file](http://forums.ultraedit.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=7015). This forum topic contains also recommendations on how to configure UltraEdit best for HTML writers who use mainly UTF-8 encoding for all HTML files. The UTF-8 detection was greatly improved with UltraEdit v24.00 which detects UTF-8 encoded characters also on in very large files on scrolling to a block containing a UTF-8 encoded character.

Unfortunately the regular expression search used by currently latest UltraEdit v22.10 and previous versions to detect a UTF-8 HTML character set declaration does not work for short HTML5 variant as reported in forum topic [Short UTF-8 charset declaration in HTML5 header](http://forums.ultraedit.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=13560). The reason is the double quote character between `charset=` and `utf-8`. I reported this by email to IDM Computer Solutions, Inc. as the referenced topic was created with the suggestion to make the small change in the regular expression to detect also short HTML5 UTF-8 declaration. The UTF-8 detection was updated later by the developers of UltraEdit for UE v24.00 and UES v17.00 as a post on referenced forum topic explains in detail.

However, when an HTML5 file is declared as UTF-8 encoded, but UltraEdit loaded it as ANSI file, the user can see the wrong loading in the status bar at bottom of main window. A small (less than 64 KB) UTF-8 encoded HTML file should result in getting

- either `U8-` and line terminator type (DOS/UNIX/MAC) displayed for users of UE < v19.00 or when using basic status bar in later versions of UE
- or `UTF-8` selected in encoding selector in status bar for users of UE v19.00 or later versions not using basic status bar.

If this is not the case, the UltraEdit user can use

- **Save As** from menu **File** and select `UTF-8 - NO BOM` for *Encoding* (Windows Vista or later) respectively *Format* (Windows 2000/XP) to convert the file from ANSI to UTF-8 without byte order mark, or
- **ASCII to UTF-8 (Unicode editing)** from submenu **Conversions** in menu **File** to convert the file from ASCII/ANSI to UTF-8 without an immediate save, or
- select **Unicode - UTF-8** via encoding selector in status bar (UE v19.00 or later only) resulting also in an immediate conversion from ASCII/ANSI to UTF-8 and enabling Unicode editing.

For the last two options the UTF-8 BOM settings at **Advanced - Settings** or **Configuration - File Handling - Save** determine saving the file without or with byte order mark on next save.

Once the word `méywe` is saved into the file using UTF-8 encoding resulting in byte stream `6D C3 A9 79 77 65` (hexadecimal) which would be displayed as `mÃ©ywe` when UTF-8 encoded file is opened in ASCII/ANSI mode (option in File - Open dialog) using Windows-1252 as code page, UltraEdit detects this file on next opening automatically as UTF-8 encoded file although `<meta charset="utf-8">` is not recognized because there is now at least one UTF-8 encoded character in the first 64 KB of the file.

To answer the question:

> What did I miss?

You missed to save the file as UTF-8 encoded file after having it opened or created as ANSI file (or more precise single byte per character encoded text file using a code page) and having it declared as UTF-8 encoded. This is a common problem of many users writing into an HTML file

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

or into an XML file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='utf-8'?>
```

and other variations depending on usage of `'` or `"` and writing either `UTF-8` or `utf-8` (and other spellings) without really knowing what this string means for the applications interpreting the bytes of the file.

[What's the best default new file format?](http://forums.ultraedit.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=15438) contains lots of useful information and links to web pages with useful information about text encoding, which one to use for which file types and how to configure UltraEdit accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Check and see if the server is sending a `charset` in the `Content-type` header. The encoding specified in that will take precedence over what you specify with the `meta` element.

Comment: This was a lead for me, in 2020's Chrome Inspect I see `"Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"`. I can only imagine this is an old server that doesn't support utf8 or something..

Answer (score 3):

Changing font-family to Calibri (or any other generally accepted font) worked for me.

**Example:**

```
<span style="font-family:Calibri">&#35; My_Text</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using MS access accdb database and PHP. It had problem in displaying the "±" character . It was displaying "�".
I added the following line in PHP at the beginning  to get it right. My problem is solved now.

```
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=ASCII');
```

Another method is to use `mb_convert_encoding($row,'UTF-8','ASCII' )`;
The header declaration is not required.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I converted the special character to decimal NCR and it worked. I have to do this because using meta tag do not work and I do not want to change my font.
There are many online unicode to decimal or hex converter.

```
Χαίρετε -> &#935;&#945;&#943;&#961;&#949;&#964;&#949;
```

Answer (score 0):

save AS HTML page, click drop down to save with encoding, select the option with UTF-8
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOFPB.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Replace `meta charset="utf-8"` with `meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"`. Maybe it will help.

Otherwise, what is your font?

Comment: No, the current charset declaration is valid HTML5 and recognised by all browsers.

Comment: tried this solution before. just tried it again. none is working.