# symbols are not loaded properly in my html

Tags: javascript, html

i have my culutrefile.js and it contains the following values

```
"standard": "#,##0.00 ¤",
"accounting": "#,##0.00 ¤;(#,##0.00 ¤)",
```

i have referred the culture file in html inside the head tag

```
<head>
<script src = "culturefile.js"> </script>
</head>
```

in browser the "¤" in myculutre.js are displayed as "�"

```
"standard": "#,##0.00 �",
"accounting": "#,##0.00 �;(#,##0.00 �)",
```

Please suggest me the solution to resolve this. Am a beginner in js

TIA

Answer (score 4):

Use [UTF-8 encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp) in your HTML document :

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

This should help display any kind of special character you might encounter.

Comment: See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-charset

Comment: i have added UTF-8 encoding like the below but my issue still exists.. :( @JeremyThille      `<head><meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src = "culturefile.js"> </script></head>`

Comment: Read the answer again.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253895/special-character-not-displaying-as-expected