# changing tabs in webpage result in character not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, html, character-encoding

When I try to switch between tabs in webpage, some of the characters are displayed correctly like m�ywe. However, when I reload the page, characters are displayed properly, there is no question mark symbol.

I have used proper encoding.

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Can anyone suggest what can be the issue? Do we need to specify character encoding format for tabs as well along with webpage. If yes, can anyone please give some reference as to how can I can do that?

Adding more info:
By tabs I mean, there is a webpage and it may have multiple tabs inside it like I have attached in picture, where London, Paris and Tokyo are 3 tabs in webpage.[image]

There is separate file for each tab and each of those files are encoded as UTF-8.
Also, I tried checking like

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

It doesn't works.

update 2:

I am trying to do something like this, so that I can set mimetype at run time but somehow `contType` is returned as undefined. What can be wrong with below code?

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState == this.HEADERS_RECEIVED){
    var contType = xhr.getResponseHeader ("Content-Type");
    }
xhr.open('POST', 'list.cgi', true);
xhr.overrideMimeType(contType);
xhr.send(formData);
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “tabs”? Have you tried `<meta charset="utf-8">`? Is the HTML file itself encoded as UTF-8 (check your editor or IDE)?

Comment: Very similar question on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253895/special-character-not-displaying-as-expected) thread with some solutions you could try.

Comment: Methods given in above thread doesnt works. I am using XMLHttpRequest and its open and send methods to open different tab. But it results in giving > wherever I have é(French character)

Comment: After searching a lot, I found if I use, 
xhr.overrideMimeType('text/xml; charset=iso-8859-1');

then characters are printed properly. But my problem is i want to support webpage in different languages. ISO-8859-1 works well for French but if chose Czech lang, again few characters are not displayed properly.

Is there any way which will first determine which encoding to use and then encode accordingly?

Comment: @Ashu `xhr` should have been mentioned in the question… but why `text/xml`? The MIME type for HTML should always be `text/html; charset=UTF-8`. Ideally, this should be configured in the server, not the client. _“I want to support webpage in different languages”_ — then use UTF-8.

Comment: @SebastianSimon sorry I was not very much aware of xhr. It is only while browsing I am coming to know how it is handled. I tried using `text/html; charset=UTF-8` but it doesn't works if language I set language to French or Dutch. I have to set it to ISO-8859-1 and after that it works fine.
Now my problem, there are few cases when I want page to be encoded in `UTF-8` and for others `ISO-8859-1` should be used. How can  I handle using xhr?

Comment: @Ashu If `charset=UTF-8` doesn’t work, then your HTML file isn’t saved in UTF-8 format. Again, check your editor settings so that it always saves as UTF-8. This will eliminate all encoding problems.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a way to make it work:

I defined hidden input type in my cgi file and returned content type from my code, so that I could detect the language and apply encoding accordingly(For some reason applying UTF-8 to French didn't worked for me).

```
var lang = document.getElementById("CurrentLanguage").value;
xhr.overrideMimeType(lang);
```

Thus, I could customize lang variable based on language used. Hope it helps others also.